# ng-model does not update until I trigger the modal again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a very basic bootstrap modal and when the user clicks ok it assigns `$scope.accountID` to a value.

It works perfectly ( it prints on the console the value I wanted)

But the ng-model does not update until I trigger the modal again and `{{accountID}}` only updates after I open the modal again.

What is this???

Controller

```
 // when user selects a row from the table
$scope.selectCustomer = function (customer) {
    BootstrapDialog.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm customer selection',
        message: 'Are you sure that you want to select the customer <b>' + customer.FIRST_NAME + " " + customer.LAST_NAME + "</b> with Account ID " + customer.ACCOUNT_ID + "?",
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
        closable: true, // <-- Default value is false
        draggable: true, // <-- Default value is false
        btnCancelLabel: 'Cancel', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
        btnOKLabel: 'Ok', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
        btnOKClass: 'btn-primary', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
        callback: function(result) {
            // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
            if(result) {
                $scope.accountID = customer.ACCOUNT_ID;
                console.log(customer.ACCOUNT_ID); // this prints correctly
            }
        }
    });
};
```

HTML

```
<pre>{{accountID}}</pre> // this only updates when I open the modal, click ok and then open modal again
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please ensure your title reflects your question (like the one that mplungjan added for you does). "When very basic stuff doesn't work" isn't remotely a useful title for your question.

Comment: I also added a really relevant tag ;)

Comment: Move *$scope.accountID = customer.ACCOUNT_ID;* before *BootstrapDialog.confirm({*

Answer (score 0):

This row

```
$scope.accountID = customer.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

defines `$scope.accountID`, but you do it in your `callback`. A `callback` is a `function` which is executed when a job is done. In this case the `callback` will be executed when a certain event happens on the `confirm`, like clicking on a button or closing the dialog. The problem is that you want to use `$scope.accountID` after the `confirm` dialog is opened, but before the button was clicked or the dialog closed. But it is not defined in this time interval, your code is not executed in a top to bottom order, because your callback is executed later than the code below it. Therefore, you will need to define `$scope.accountID` at an earlier stage, in our case before `confirm` is called:

```
 // when user selects a row from the table
$scope.selectCustomer = function (customer) {
    $scope.accountID = customer.ACCOUNT_ID;
    BootstrapDialog.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm customer selection',
        message: 'Are you sure that you want to select the customer <b>' + customer.FIRST_NAME + " " + customer.LAST_NAME + "</b> with Account ID " + customer.ACCOUNT_ID + "?",
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
        closable: true, // <-- Default value is false
        draggable: true, // <-- Default value is false
        btnCancelLabel: 'Cancel', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
        btnOKLabel: 'Ok', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
        btnOKClass: 'btn-primary', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
        callback: function(result) {
            // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
            if(result) {
                console.log(customer.ACCOUNT_ID); // this prints correctly
            }
        }
    });
};
```